# Sheaf Cohomology respects Products

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, sheaf-cohomology

Let $(\mathcal{F}_{\lambda})_{\lambda}$ a family of sheaves on the space $X$. Consider the sheaf product $\prod_{\lambda} \mathcal{F}_{\lambda} $.

My question is what are the weakest conditions for the $\mathcal{F}_{\lambda}$ such that the sheaf cohomology respects the product, therefore

$$ H^r(X, \prod_{\lambda} \mathcal{F}_{\lambda}) \cong \prod_{\lambda} H^r (X,\mathcal{F}_{\lambda})$$
 holds (for $r>0$; case $r=0$ is always true because global section functor is right adjoint, so preserves limits) .

Remarks: This question arises from my former thread: [Sheaf Cohomology of Injective Sheaves respects Products](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2684022/sheaf-cohomology-of-injective-sheaves-respects-products/2684261#2684261)
where the $\mathcal{F}_{\lambda}$ were injective.

Comment: If you understand how to calculate sheaf cohomology by taking an injective resolution, this should follow immediately from the answer to your other question.

Comment: @KReiser This does not seem so clear to me as arbitrary product are not exact in the category of sheaves. Hence, if $\mathcal{I}_\lambda$ is a resolution of $\mathcal{F}_\lambda$, then $\prod \mathcal{I}_\lambda$ is not necessarily a resolution of $\prod\mathcal{F}_\lambda$.

Comment: Well, if we have for each $\lambda$ an injective resoltion 

$$0 \to \mathcal{F}_{\lambda} \to \mathcal{I}_{\lambda} ^0 \to \mathcal{I}_{\lambda} ^1 \to \mathcal{I}_{\lambda} ^2 \to ...$$

then indeed for each $i$ the products $\prod_{\lambda} \mathcal{I}_{\lambda} ^i$ are also injective but is

$$0 \to \prod_{\lambda} \mathcal{F}_{\lambda}  \to \prod_{\lambda} \mathcal{I}_{\lambda} ^0 \to \prod_{\lambda} \mathcal{I}_{\lambda} ^1 \to \prod_{\lambda} \mathcal{I}_{\lambda} ^2 \to ...$$

an injective ***resolution***? Especially exact? That's the 1. problem.

Comment: The second is: By definition $H^r(X, \mathcal{F}_{\lambda}) := Ker(\mathcal{I}_{\lambda} ^r \to \mathcal{I}_{\lambda} ^{r+1})/im(\mathcal{I}_{\lambda} ^{r-1} \to \mathcal{I}_{\lambda} ^r)$ but I'm here quite unsure why 

$$Ker(\prod_{\lambda} \mathcal{I}_{\lambda} ^r \to \prod_{\lambda} \mathcal{I}_{\lambda} ^{r+1})/Im(\prod_{\lambda} \mathcal{I}_{\lambda} ^{r-1} \to \prod_{\lambda} \mathcal{I}_{\lambda} ^r) = \prod_{\lambda} Ker(\mathcal{I}_{\lambda} ^r \to \mathcal{I}_{\lambda} ^{r+1})/im(\mathcal{I}_{\lambda} ^{r-1} \to \mathcal{I}_{\lambda} ^r)  $$

should hold?

Comment: @KarlPeter No by definition $H^r(X,\mathcal{F}_\lambda)=\ker(I^r_\lambda(X)\rightarrow I^{r+1}_\lambda(X))/\operatorname{im}(I_\lambda^{r-1}(X)\rightarrow I^r_\lambda(X))$ (note that you take the global sections). Then infinite product are exact in the category of abelian groups, and global sections commute with infinite product as well, so your last equality hold in full generality. Only the first problem is serious as I pointed out in my previous comment. And it is a critical one as sheaf cohomology does not commute with infinite product in general.

Comment: Yes, sorry, of course there are always token the kernels and images of induced maps $\mathcal{I}^r _{\lambda}(X) \to \mathcal{I}^{r+1} _{\lambda}(X)$ on global sections. So, when we know that global section functor respects products (I suppose that it can be shown on level of stalks or that product of sheaves is a sheaf ... or does there exist an other common way to see it?)

Comment: then showing $$Ker(\prod_{\lambda} \mathcal{I}_{\lambda} ^r(X)\to \prod_{\lambda} \mathcal{I}_{\lambda} ^{r+1}(X))/Im(\prod_{\lambda} \mathcal{I}_{\lambda} ^{r-1}(X) \to \prod_{\lambda} \mathcal{I}_{\lambda} ^r(X)) = \prod_{\lambda} Ker(\mathcal{I}_{\lambda} ^r(X) \to \mathcal{I}_{\lambda} ^{r+1}(X))/im(\mathcal{I}_{\lambda} ^{r-1}(X) \to \mathcal{I}_{\lambda} ^r(X))  $$

is a set theoretical problem which follows because the map $\prod_{\lambda} \mathcal{I}_{\lambda} ^r(X)\to \prod_{\lambda} \mathcal{I}_{\lambda} ^{r+1}(X)$ is defined componentwise?

Comment: Yes global section functor preserve product. It has been explained in your last post (the one you linked) : it has a left adjoint so preserve all kind of limits, in particular product. Or you can prove it directly : yes the presheaf product is already a sheaf. As for the last part : yes in module categories, arbitrary product are exact as I said before.